# PHP Error de sintaxis syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, mysql

Me encuentro con el siguiente error en un archivo PHP:

```php
syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

En la siguiente linea de código:

```php
function mysql(...$args){ return mysql_db_query(...$args); }
```

¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: y esa línea de código que pones es así tal cual o la has modificado para la pregunta? es que me sobran los ..., y si la has modificado y no vemos los argumentos tampoco podremos ayudarte mucho. [ask] - [tour]

Comment: @ÓscarNovás es así tal cual, es de un archivo php que me descargué y lo incluí en mi código.

Comment: Fabito mira información sobre mysql y php en la propia pagina de https://php.net veras ejemplos... Eso suena a una linea de código donde $args son varios argumentos. Normalmente en el mysql_db_query los argumentos que se le pasan es la consulta en string mas el objeto de la conexión a mysql

Comment: El operador `...` ([unpacking](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list.new)) esta disponible a partir de PHP 5.6+

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido mysql_db_query está obsoleto, hay que usar mysqli o pdo_mysql, verifica la versión de php que estas usando mediante el comando ``php -v`` desde la linea de comandos.

Comment: Eso parece sacado de [aquí](https://github.com/rubo77/php-mysql-fix/blob/master/fix_mysql.inc.php), y es para que corra en PHP 7 o superior. Revisa tu versión de PHP antes de usarlo y si lo usas que sea de forma completa con un include, pues a su vez sustituye la función `mysql_db_query` en el mismo script. No lo saques a cachos porque no te funcionará.